# Why does my function work with checkboxes and not radios?

Tags: javascript, checkbox, radio-button

I am using a function to show multiple checked checkboxes and radios onClick of a radio.  Unfortunately, the function only works if the trigger input is a checkbox.  I need it to be a radio.  How can I alter my function to work for a radio?

Here is my script:

```
<script>
$(function() {
  enable_cb();
  $("#groupa").click(enable_cb);
});

function enable_cb() {
  if (this.checked) {
     $("input.groupa").prop("checked", this.checked);
  } else {
     $("input.groupa").removeAttr("checked");

  }
}
</script>
```

Here is my html:

```
<input type="radio" id="groupa" checked="checked">Group A<br />
<input type="checkbox" class="groupa"> A<br />
<input type="radio" class="groupa"> B<br />
<input type="checkbox" class="groupa"> C<br />
<input type="radio" class="groupa"> D<br />
<input type="checkbox" class="groupa"> E<br />
```

Comment: [I don't get the question](http://jsfiddle.net/rnFtr/).

Comment: Please describe what "works" means. Do you want to have only 1 radio button checked when either is clicked?

Comment: @AdamPlocher I am using an id for the trigger and a class for the checkboxes I want triggered.  "#" indicates id, and "." indicates class.

Comment: @rontornambe When the type="checkbox" id="groupa", the function works.  Meaning that if the input type="radio" - it doesn't work.

Comment: radio buttons are not toggles like checkboxes unless at least one other radio button has a like "name" property specified. The difference is that when the checkbox is clicked "this.checked" is "false" and when the already checked radio button is clicked, "this.checked" remains "true".

Answer (score 0):

```
function enable_cb() {

    if( $(this).is(':checked') ) 
    {
         $("input.groupa").attr("checked",'checked');
    } 
    else {
        $("input.groupa").removeAttr("checked");

    }

}
```

Comment: You might want to consider adding some text to explain why you think this would help